# Sharing Entire Google Photos Library using a Link

Tags: google-photos

How can I share a link to my entire Google Photos collection, so that someone can look at the entire file/collection without me first transferring them to a Google Drive folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can't share your entire collection. You can share individual photos (movies, animations) or albums.

You'd need to put all of your photos into one album and share that.

(Drive is similar. You can't share your root directory; you have to pick a subfolder.)

Comment: Placing all photos on a single album and sharing that, will work, burb you have to add new photos manually afterwards. Setting up Google drive to create a '"Google photos " folder and then sharing this folder also world, and every new uploaded photo will be automatically shared with those you've given access to

Answer (score -1):

Add them to a shared album and share the link

Comment: Thanks ale and silencer.  However, in the folders in Google Drive, the photos can't be sorted by "date created" (date photo was taken), and i wanted to share then in chronological order.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that albums that are created in "Google Photos", unlike photo files in "Google Drive" do allow one to sort by date created.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This seems to be an answer to the question you asked in [this comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106352/sharing-google-photos-link/106401#comment93223_106359). That's not how Stack Exchange works; it's not a discussion forum. If you have a separate question, ask it separately. You'd do well to take the site [tour] and review the [help], specifically [ask].